# String and line formatting in Python

Tags: python, string, formatting, line

I want to make the following command to be formatted in python, in other to comply with the 80 character per line policy:

```
cmd = """elastic-mapreduce --create --alive \
--instance-type m1.xlarge\
--num-instances 5 \
--supported-product mapr \
--name m7 \
--args "--edition,m7"
"""
```

Although in the code it will look like multiple lines, when `cmd` gets executed I wanted it to look like

```
elastic-mapreduce --create --alive --instance-type m1.xlarge --num-instances 5 supported-product mapr name m7 args "--edition,m7"
```

That's a similar problem I'm having here:

```
raise ValueError, "%s hadoop %s version is not supported" % (self.distribution, version)
```

that line it's too long,  I would like to do something like:

```
raise ValueError,\ 
"%s hadoop %s version is not supported" % (self.distribution, version)
```

Comment: And ... what's the question? If it's about coding style you should have asked at codereview.SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your first one bit of code you could write a method to 'linearize' your whitespace

```
 import re
 def linearize_whitespace_regex(text):
      formatted = text.strip().replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' ').replace('\t',' ')
      formatted = re.sub(r'\s{2,}',' ',formatted)
      return formatted
```

I used the regular expressions library, this of course could be accomplished without that import using your own parsing:

```
def linearize_whitespace_manual(text):
      formatted = text.strip().replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' ').replace('\t',' ')
      ws_buf = ''
      format_buf = ''
      for i in formatted:
          if i == ' ':
                if len(ws_buf) < 1:
                    ws_buf += i
          else:
                format_buf += ws_buf + i
                ws_buf = ''
      return format_buf
```

and output:

```
>>> cmd = """elastic-mapreduce --create --alive \
... --instance-type m1.xlarge\
... --num-instances 5 \
... --supported-product mapr \
... --name m7 \
... --args "--edition,m7"
... """
>>> linearize_whitespace_regex(cmd)
'elastic-mapreduce --create --alive --instance-type m1.xlarge--num-instances 5 --supported-product mapr --name m7 --args "--edition,m7"'
>>> linearize_whitespace_manual(cmd)
'elastic-mapreduce --create --alive --instance-type m1.xlarge--num-instances 5 --supported-product mapr --name m7 --args "--edition,m7"'
```

As for your second question raising exceptions can also be done in this fashion:

```
raise Exception("My error message")
```

So you could write it like this:

```
raise ValueError("%s hadoop %s version is not supported" % (self.distribution, version))
```

And fulfill your line requirement in any of these ways:

```
raise ValueError("%s hadoop %s version is not supported"
    % (self.distribution, version))


raise ValueError(
    "%s hadoop %s version is not supported" % (self.distribution, version))


raise ValueError(
     "%s hadoop %s version is not supported"
     % (self.distribution, version)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `\n` should insert a new line.